# Swift unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a most basic calculator, learned from the Stanford online course. I only made a "multiply" button for it to multiply two values in Array "operandStack", but every time my program crashed and i don't know why.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController
        {
         @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!
         var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber:Bool = false

        @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
               let digit = sender.currentTitle!
              if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
                 display.text = display.text! + digit
               } else {
                  display.text =  digit
                  userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
            }
         }

       @IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
           let operation = sender.currentTitle!
           if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
             enter()
            }
           switch operation {
             case "×":
              if operandStack.count >= 2 {
                displayValue = operandStack.removeLast() * operandStack.removeLast()
                enter()
            }
             default: break
           }
        }
 var operandStack = Array<Double> ()

       @IBAction func enter() {
          userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
          operandStack.append(displayValue)
          println("operandStack = \(operandStack)")
        }


       var displayValue: Double {
         get {
            return   NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }
        set {
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Can you post crash description? You have quite a lot of unsafe unwrapping  in your code, thus its not easy to pinpoint source of problem.

Comment: the output is like this:  operandStack = [6.0]
operandStack = [6.0, 5.0]
2015-03-14 08:56:50.334 Calculator[2640:62426] -[Calculator.ViewController operate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fedc161c8a0
2015-03-14 08:56:50.339 Calculator[2640:62426] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Calculator.ViewController operate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fedc161c8a0'

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem when I noticed my plus sign, less sign and divided sign was connected with 2 Sent Event in Touch Up inside (View Controller -> appendDigit and operate). I disconnected my signs from appendDigit and it is working ok. Even I added a parameter in sender function

```
@IBAction func enter(sender: AnyObject?) {
    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
    operandStack.append(displayValue)
    println("operandStack = \(operandStack)")
}
```

and I used the enter function like that: enter(sender).
Another issue was this line of code:

```
return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
```

I changed by this line:

```
return (display.text! as NSString).doubleValue
```

as I saw in this disscusion [fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - Stanford Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420232/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-stanfor)

I hope that helps programmer checking Stanford course.